# Nodemailer Not Sending Email on Vercel but Works in Development

Tags: next.js, nodemailer, vercel, next.js13

I'm trying to use Nodemailer in NextJS 13.4 and it works in development mode, but not on Vercel production. Vercel build log shows code 200.

I tried to apply methods found on other questions with any luck.

Please see code below:

```
"use server";

export async function sendEmail(data: Inputs) {
  fetch(checkEnvironment().concat("/api/contact"), {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  }).then((res) => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
      return res.json();
    }
  });
}
```

```
//api/contact/route.ts


export async function POST(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const { name, company, email, phone, message } = await req.json();
  console.log(name);
  //require("dotenv").config();
  let nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    port: 465,
    host: "smtp.****.com",
    auth: {
      user: username,
      pass: password,
    },
    secure: true,
  });

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    transporter.sendMail(mailData, function (err: any, info: any) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log(info);
        resolve(info);
        return NextResponse.json({ error: "All Done" }, { status: 200 });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Same problem, and very similar setup with gmail.